# trying to wget my stock portfolio

Tags: http, session, scripting, cookies, wget

I'm trying to read my stock portfolio into a script. The following works with NAB Online Trading but not [Bell Direct](https://www.belldirect.com.au/).

- install the [Export Domain Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12360) Firefox addon
- log in to my online broker with Firefox
- save the domain cookies to a file (eg `cookies.txt`)
- `wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookies.txt -O folio.htm https://...`(portfolio URL)

-- The idea being to reuse the browser's login session. When I try it with Bell Direct, `wget` is redirected to the login page. I get the same results with `curl`. What am I missing? Is there some state that is stored in the browser besides in the cookies? Bell isn't using "basic authentication" because the login page is a form for username / password - it doesn't pop up the browser's built-in login dialog.

Here is what happens (under Windows XP with Cygwin):

> `$ wget --server-response --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookies-bell.txt -O folio-bell.htm https://www.belldirect.com.au/trade/portfoliomanager/`
>   `--2009-12-14 10:52:08--  https://www.belldirect.com.au/trade/portfoliomanager/`
>   `Resolving www.belldirect.com.au... 202.164.26.80`
>   `Connecting to www.belldirect.com.au|202.164.26.80|:443... connected.`
>   `WARNING: cannot verify www.belldirect.com.au's certificate, issued by '/C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Server CA/emailAddress=server-certs@thawte.com':`
>   `Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.`
>   `HTTP request sent, awaiting response...`
>   `HTTP/1.1 302 Found`
>   `Connection: keep-alive`
>   `Date: Sun, 13 Dec 2009 23:52:16 GMT`
>   `Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0`
>   `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`
>   `X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727`
>   `Location: /account/login.html?redirect=https://www.belldirect.com.au/trade/portfoliomanager/index.html`
>   `Cache-Control: private`
>   `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
>   `Content-Length: 229`
>   `Location: /account/login.html?redirect=https://www.belldirect.com.au/trade/portfoliomanager/index.html [following]`
>   `...`

Comment: Any chance you can provide us with a test / fake login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the server is validating the session based on User-Agent as well as the cookie. Check what user-agent your Firefox install is using (perhaps use WhatIsMyUserAgent.com if you don't know it), and try using that exact same user agent in your Wget call (via the --user-agent="..." parameter).

Comment: Yup, that did it. Have some rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST the login form variables, then, with those cookies, goto the inner page.

http://www.trap17.com/index.php/automatic-login-curl_t38162.html for some example code.

Comment: But I've already logged in using the browser. I want to just fetch the portfolio page using whatever state the browser's stored for the login session. BTW I followed your link and it didn't seem to be what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

The login is encrypted over the HTTPS protocol, and you do not provide a certificate.  Perhaps belldirect requires a valid certificate for client authentication.

You can export a certificate in Firefox by clicking the highlighted blue portion of the URL > More Information > Security Tab > View Certificate > Details > Export.  Then, you can use the `--certificate=filename` option to specify the exported certificate in your `wget` command.

Comment: I tried it (trying various options for "Save as Type"), and still got `cannot verify www.belldirect.com.au's certificate` :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the referrer too.